# Send large amount of data to user efficently in CSV format

Tags: jquery, asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

Please give me an advise on efficiently retrieving CSV report after I have retrieved a large amount of data from sql server using a very complex stored procedure ( sp ).

I run heavy computations in my sp and returns large amount of data from it. I display it using jquery table. I can apply paging at the time of display.

Problem is, I have to make this large data downloadable for the user in lightest format ( CSV ) in one go.

Currently,when I get this data, I am storing it in a hidden field and send to the user on button click.

BUT I don't think it's optimal because my data could be very very big ( eg: 300, 00000 rows with at least 10 cols ).

Plz help me to do it more efficiently.

I store in hidden field to reduce the round trip to get this same data again.

NOTE: I am using web-form and make a call to REST API to get the large amount of data using AJAX.

Thanks,

Comment: SQL server will keep the sp data cached for a short period (dependent upon how often the query is run and current load), Or you can Cache the data on the server using ASP.NET Cache, and provide a button to download as CSV, and make your paging access the Cache first, and if the data is not in the Cache, then re-run the SQL.

Answer (score 0):

for that amount of data, i recommend you use another staging database and a table. Maybe just truncate the table for each run and insert the date from your usp.

Depneding on how you access this data, better not put a clusterd index, that will enable to write fast into the table.